# sort: wrong order when comparing according to numerical value

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I'm trying to sort the lines in the following file according to numerical value in the second column:

```
2 117.336136
1 141.003021
1 342.389160
1 169.059006
1 208.173370
1 117.608192
```

However, for some reason, the following command returns the lines in the wrong order:

```sh
cat file | sort -n -k2
```

```
1 117.608192
2 117.336136
1 141.003021
1 169.059006
1 208.173370
1 342.389160
```

The first two lines are swapped. For other lines, the content of the first column does not affect the result.

Without the `-k` argument, the `sort` works exacly as expected:

```sh
cat file | cut -d' ' -f2 | sort -n
```

```
117.336136
117.608192
141.003021
169.059006
208.173370
342.389160
```

Why is that? Did I misunderstand the meaning of the `-k` argument?

Additional information:

- `LC_ALL=cs_CZ.utf8`
- `sort --version` gives `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.31`

Comment: `sort -n -k2 file` (You don't need `cat`) works as expected for me.

Comment: @DaBler : It also works for me, and evern your unnecessary `cat` should make no difference. I could imagine that you get a wrong result if you have some hidden characters in the file, or - for instance - have Unicode-digits coming from an alphabet not recognized by `sort`, but in this case, your approach using `cut` would not have worked either.

Comment: @Shawn It is not true. For me, it sorts equally wrong.

Comment: `-n` doesn't compare floats, only numbers. So only `117` is compared. GNU sort has `-g`. Because fields are the same (and sort is not stable), then the comparision re-starts sorting lexically from the first field. I guess you could `-k2n -k2,4` assuming the fields  are always 3 digits, dot, 6 digits.

Comment: @DaBler: What does `locale thousands_sep` return?

Comment: @Inian The `locale thousands_sep` prints empty line.

Comment: @KamilCuk The same problem with `-g`.

Comment: Try `sort -s -g -k2.2` ? Ach `thousends_sep`. Maybe `LC_ALL=C sort -g -k2.2`?

Comment: @DaBler: Can you try `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sort -g -k2.2`

Comment: Using the `-V` if available maybe: `sort -Vk2`

Comment: @KamilCuk LC_ALL=C right in front of the `sort -n -k2` gives the correct order. So it must be a locale issue.

Comment: @Inian Also LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 gives the right order.

Comment: What I do not understand is why `cut -d' ' -f2 | sort -n` works on any locale while `sort -n -k2` doest not.

Comment: Because when numbers are compared `117` and they are the same, then `sort` continues to sort the lines lexically. So it compares `3` with `6` _lexically_, and sorts the lines. Compare with `cut -d' ' -f2 | sort -s -n`. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64102/why-is-sort-changing-the-order-of-lines-with-identical-sort-keys)

Comment: @KamilCuk Still don't understand why the behavior of `sort -n` and `sort -n -k2` differs. Anyhow the problem is specific to the `cs_CZ.utf8` locale.

Comment: Because last resort comparision. Ex. with `1 117.608192
2 117.336136` - `-n` compares _only the 117_ (because in cs_CZ decimal_point is `,` not `.`). Then as last resort comoparision the _whole line_ is compared. So the initial `1` is compared with initial `2` and lines are ordered. With `117.336136
117.608192` last resort comparision compares the whole line, so `3` is compared with `6` and the order is determinate.

Comment: @KamilCuk Ahh, my fault. I missed the keyword "comparison of the whole lines". Now it all fits perfectly. You are welcome to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sort sorts files according to your locale settings.
As mentioned by @KamilCuk, the decimal separator for `cs_CZ` is `,` instead of `.`. You can override the default locale with `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` or `LC_ALL=C` (no UTF-8 support), to use the C local settings for sorting.

For sorting floating point values, you need `-g` as `-n` just sorts the integer part.

Also important when using sort is to restrict the sorting to the specific column `-k 2,2g` as by default sort also will use the rest of the line for sorting.

```bash
$ LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sort -k 2,2g test_sort.txt 
2 117.336136
1 117.608192
1 141.003021
1 169.059006
1 208.173370
1 342.389160

$ LC_ALL=C sort -k 2,2g test_sort.txt 
2 117.336136
1 117.608192
1 141.003021
1 169.059006
1 208.173370
1 342.389160
```

```bash
$ printf '1\t5.3\t6.0\n2\t5.3\t5.0\n'
1   5.3 6.0
2   5.3 5.0

# Sort uses the rest of the line to sort.
$ printf '1\t5.3\t6.0\n2\t5.3\t5.0\n' | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sort -k 2
2   5.3 5.0
1   5.3 6.0

# Sort only uses the second column.
$ printf '1\t5.3\t6.0\n2\t5.3\t5.0\n' | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sort -k 2,2
1   5.3 6.0
2   5.3 5.0
```